# How to connect to remote DB server with IP address and mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysqli

I have php 7 installed on my digital ocean server. I can connect to localhost DB using mysqli function, but when i try to connect to external DB server using IP address, it gives following error msg:

mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out

I added "skip-name-resolve" in my.cnf file and restarted mysql but still facing same issue. 
How can i connect to external DB using IP address with mysqli_connect function ?
I tried following two:

mysqli_connect(IP_Address,DB_username,DB_Password,DB Name,"3306");

mysqli_connect(IP_Address,DB_username,DB_Password);